# Ant task to automatize spring roo operations?

Tags: spring, ant, spring-roo

I need to automatize spring roo tasks from an ant `build.xml`. Is it somehow possible? Maybe there is an ant task lib for the job?

Using ant instead of maven/gradle/... isn't my decision and I can't do anything with it.

Calling the roo shell with an exec task is only a last resort, I want a solution to that I don't need to step out from the jvm of the ant process.

Comment: To the googlers of the future: In the absence of valid answers, the question remains open indefinitely. If you have an answer, I wait you with my upvoting/accepting capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roo Shell executes over **OSGi environment** and requires it to run (uses OSGi dependency injections to get component in runtime). So, as Ant runs as simple java application, **no way to run Roo shell as an Ant Task** but use *ant exec task* (as you already comment).

Sorry.

Comment: Ok, but the roo.sh (roo.bat) _has_ a way to somehow invoke roo. It simply uses a java -jar call to do the task. Why were ant unable to do the same, even if it needed to start an osgi environment for the job?

Comment: What roo.sh  does is to run Apache Felix that loads all Roo components like the commands you said.

Comment: @eruiz Maybe it were then enough to start felix from ant? Isn't there a felix/ant integration?

Comment: @eruiz Ok, but if a single java command _can_ call felix, which calls the osgi components and start spring roo, _why_ is the same impossible from ant?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean ... Ant is what is, take a look to user guide to know more about Ant targets.

Answer (score 1):

The project generated with Roo is as any other Maven project, so you may use a `exec` task. Something like this:

```
<target name="mvn-install">
    <exec executable="mvn">
        <arg value="clean" />
        <arg value="install" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Thank you, but maybe you didn't read my last sentence: "Calling the roo shell with an exec task is only a last resort, I want a solution to that I don't need to step out from the jvm of the ant process." You also didn't understand, that I want to call roo operations ("entity", "perform", etc) and not maven operations. If it weren't an answer to my question, you got a downvote and a "not an answer" flag.

Comment: So, jmvivo is right, you cannot call Roo Shell commands from Ant, Maven, ... all Roo commands are OSGi components so you need the OSGi container running to execute them.

Comment: Yes, and the roo.sh starts this osgi container, and exactly this is which I have to do as an ant "java" task...